# Python DEAP individual to an AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, genetic-programming

I'm trying to convert an individual (a gp program) into python code. However when I call evaluate() I'm getting an error I'm not sure how to fix. I'm solving [symbolic regression](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/examples/gp_symbreg.html) problem and these are my primitives.

```
    pset = gp.PrimitiveSet("MAIN", 1)
    pset.addPrimitive(operator.add, 2)
    pset.addPrimitive(operator.sub, 2)
    pset.addPrimitive(operator.mul, 2)
    pset.addPrimitive(safeDiv, 2)
    pset.addEphemeralConstant(lambda: random.randint(-1,1))
    pset.renameArguments(ARG0='x')
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: As the main developper of DEAP gp module, I recommend you to move your question to our mailing-list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/deap-users, where we will be able to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with individuals that have an argument the correct way to evaluate them is through [lambdify](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/0.9/api/gp.html?highlight=lambdify#deap.gp.lambdify) because evaluate creates an individual that is wrapped around a function without an argument. Sadly you cannot convert individuals into python code. The individual is represented in the form of [mul,x,mul,add,1,x] for example which is after that mapped to the primitive functions set in the toolbox and this is done because it's faster then creating python code or an AST and executing it.

For future DEAP related problem I would recommend doing what CmdNtrf suggested which is join the DEAP google group where you can ask your specific questions.

Hope that helps in the case of future dwellers.